# Query points using SQL Server 2008 geography type

Tags: sql-server-2008, latitude-longitude, geography

I have a table with the geography type and I want to run a query to find all rows within 25 miles of a specific lat/long.  What would the query look like to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
select *
from local_events
where _your_geography_column_.STDistance(geography::Point(_your_lat_,_your_long_, 4326)) < ((_your_miles_ * 1000) * 0.621371192)
```

Comment: the *1000 is turning meters into Kilometers, and the *.621371192 is turning kilometers into miles - in case you were wonder like I was